# I keep getting a UTF error when transferring image data as bytes over a socket

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, networking

I'm trying to send images from my computer to my phone by using a Java program connect to an Android app.

The code I use to send the image:

```
byte[] data = imageToByteArray(img);
sendMessage(Main.imageCheck + data.length);
out.write(data);
out.flush();
```

This code is run from the Java program on my computer. The sendMessage() method is:

```
public void sendMessage(String s) {
    if (out != null && server.isConnected()) {
        try {
            out.writeUTF(s);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code I use to receive the image and other data:

```
while ((input = in.readUTF()) != null) {
    if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(pulseCheckMessage)) {
        if (input.contains(imageCheck)) {
            //byte[] data = Base64.decode(input.replace(imageCheck, ""), Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] data = new byte[Integer.parseInt(input.replace(imageCheck, ""))];
            int length = in.read(data);
            updateScreenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, length);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(updateUiRunnable);
        } else {
            inLine = "Received: " + input;
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(updateUiRunnable);
        }
    }

    pulseTakenTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pulseCheckReceived = true;
    isAlive = true;
}
```

The commented out code (including the base64 class) was when I was sending the image data as a string by using Base64.encode to convert the byte[] array to a string to send over, which worked without a problem except that it was too slow. So I decided to send the bytes over which I thought would be faster.

imageCheck and Main.imageCheck are strings that are the same. The app receives that string and recognizes it and expects a byte[] array so it tries to do in.read(data) however I get an error:

```
ERROR: java.nio.charset.ModifiedUtf8.decode(ModifiedUtf8.java:57)
ERROR: java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:444)
ERROR: java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:438)
ERROR: java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:433)
ERROR: com.mangopearapples.pccontroller.MainActivity.run(MainActivity.java:238)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `sendMessage()` do?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the post to include the `sendMessage()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `int length = in.read(data);` doesn't read all the bytes that have been sent, [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> Reads **some number** of bytes from the contained input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. **The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer**

(emphasis mine)

So, the next iteration tries to read the unread bytes of the image as UTF, and it fails. Always use a loop to read bytes from a stream, which stops once all the expected number of bytes have been read.

To confirm that this is the real problem, debug and see if the length returned matches with the actual length.

Comment: If that is the case, he should consider using `input.readFully(data);` instead.

Comment: JB Nizet, you are right. The length from in.read(data) is different to the one sent.
I followed Josh M's advice and used readFully(data) instead. It works alot better however I still get the error maybe after around 15 seconds. (I am sending a lot of images as I am trying to send my computer screen to my phone)

Comment: You can't readFully, since you're in a loop reading N images. readFully() blocks until there is nothing to read anymore from the stream, i.e. the sender has closed the stream.